# ¿Cómo leer líneas de un archivo de texto en un rango en particular con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

¡Buen día!

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo una lista que puede contener `n` elementos

```
index_info = []

    with open('data.txt', 'r+') as f:
        text = f.readlines()
        for line in text:
            if line.startswith('Pokemon '):
                a = line
                index_info.append(text.index(a))
```

Tengo que leer cada línea del archivo con base a los elementos de la lista, por ejemplo, tomando en cuenta la siguiente lista:

```
[0, 63, 148, 212, 277, 354, 414, 471, 595, 721, 834, 898, 960, 1019]
```

Tengo que leer y guardar en un diccionario cada línea del archivo de la 0 a la 63, luego de la 63 a la 148 y así sucesivamente. Por lo que, para este caso, tendría almacenados 14 diccionarios.

No logro crear la función para realizar esta iteración, ¿alguien podría darme una idea?
¡Gracias!

```
for i in range(index_info[0], index_info[1]):
    print("Test") #Se imprime 63 veces
```

Este es un ejemplo del archivo:

```
Pokemon: Charmander
    Tipo: Fuego
    Habilidades:
        Normales: Mar Llamas
        Oculta: Poder Solar
Pokemon: Bulbasaur
    Tipo: Planta
    Habilidades:
        Normales: Espesura
        Oculta: Clorofila
    Peso: 6.9 kg
Pokemon: Pikachu
    Tipo: Electrico
    Habilidades:
        Normales: Estática
        Oculta: Pararrayos
    Peso: 6 kg
```

***Código con base a la respuesta***

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import json
index_info = []



json_data = {"pokemones": []}


pokemones = []
types = []
weight = []

with open('pokemon.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

    for indice, line in enumerate(text):
        if line.startswith('Pokemon'):
            #print(line)
            index_info.append(indice)

    
    for inicio, fin in zip(index_info, index_info[1:]):
        trozo = text[inicio:fin]
        #print(trozo)
        #procesar_pokemon(trozo)
        for line in trozo:
            if line.startswith('Pokemon'):
                pokemon = line[9:len(line)].strip()
                pokemones.append(pokemon)
            
            if line.startswith('    Tipo'):
                type = line[9:len(line)].strip()
                types.append(type)

            if line.startswith('    Peso'):
                w = line[9:len(line)].strip()
                weight.append(w)

    print(index_info)    
    print(index_info[1:])

        
    #print(pokemones)
    #print(types)
    #print(weight)

for i in range(len(pokemones)):
    json_data["pokemones"].append({
                "name": pokemones[i],
                "type": types[i],
                #"weight": weight[i]
                
            })


print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, default=str))
```

Comment: Hola Hugo! tú codigo da problemas de sintaxis por la identación, puedes editar la pregunta e identarlo correctamente. Por otro lado no entiendo en que forma lo quieres guardar en un diccionario ¿Cuál sería la clave, y cual el valor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero trataré de entender qué haces aquí:

```
index_info = []

with open('data.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('Pokemon '):
            a = line
            index_info.append(text.index(a))
```

Parece que intentas crear una lista llamada `index_info` que contiene los índices de todas las líneas que comienzan por `'Pokemon '`

Si efectivamente es eso lo que intentas hacer, lo estás haciendo de forma un poco complicada al usar `text.index(a)` para buscar el índice de la línea. Realmente puedes iterar usando `enumerate()`, que te da los índices además de las líneas:

```
index_info = []
with open('data.txt', 'r+') as f:
    text = f.readlines()

for indice, line in enumerate(text):
    if line.startswith('Pokemon '):
       index_info.append(indice)
```

De paso he sacado el bucle que procesa las líneas del contexto `with()` pues una vez has leido todas las líneas en la variable `text` ya se puede cerrar el fichero.

Seguidamente entiendo que quieres "separar" la lista de líneas que hay en `text` en trozos, según los índices guardados en `index_info`. En el fondo supongo que se trata de que cada uno de esos trozos contenga información sobre un Pokemon en particular. Supongo que tendrás algún tipo de función al que le pasas la lista con las líneas sobre ese pokemon, para que extraiga la información correspondiente.

Este "troceado" lo puedes hacer así:

```
for inicio, fin in zip(index_info, index_info[1:]):
   trozo = texto[inicio:fin]
   procesar_pokemon(trozo)
```

Aqui el truco lo hace la función `zip()` que va "emparejando" elementos de los dos iterables que recibe como parámetro. Yo le paso la lista `index_info` como primer parámetro y la misma lista pero empezando en la posición 1 en vez de la 0. Así, por ejemplo si `index_info` contiene `[0, 63, 148, 212, 277]`, entonces le estaría pasando esa misma lista como primer parámetro y la lista `[63, 148, 212, 277]` como segundo parámetro.

Al ir emparejando elementos de ambas listas, tomaría el primer elemento de la primera lista (que vale 0) y lo emparejaría con el primer elemento de la segunda lista (que vale 63). La pareja sería por tanto `(0, 63)` y eso es lo que recojo en las variables del bucle `inicio, fin`. Así que las puedo usar para extraer el *slice* `texto[inicio:fin]`.

En cada iteración del bucle voy extrayendo de este modo los índices de cada "rodaja".

## Bonus

Si, como supongo, se trata de procesar por separado el conjunto de líneas que pertenecen a cada Pokemon, puedes usar otra estrategia que es más eficiente en el uso de memoria. En realidad esto sólo es relevante si tu fichero tuviera muchísimas líneas (millones). En tu enfoque lees el fichero completo y lo guardas en la lista `texto`. Si el fichero fuera enorme, esa lista estaría ocupando mucha memoria.

En el enfoque que sugiero a continuación no lees el fichero entero, sino que lo vas procesando línea por línea, acumulando estas líneas en una lista, hasta que detectes que ya tienes todos los datos de un Pokemon. Entonces procesas la lista con los datos de ese pokemon y luego descartas la lista para procesar el siguiente. De este modo aunque en el fichero hubiera millones de pokemons, la lista de líneas nunca crece demasiado pues contendría sólo las que corresponden a un único pokemon.

Esta sería la implementación:

```
lista_lineas_pokemon = []

with open('data.txt', 'r+') as f:
  for linea in f:    # Esto solo lee una línea de cada vez
    if linea.startswith('Pokemon '):
       procesar_pokemon(lista_lineas_pokemon)
       lista_lineas_pokemon = []
    lista_lineas_pokemon.append(linea)
```

Observa cómo en cada iteración del bucle se va añadiendo una línea a la lista `lista_lineas_pokemon`, pero tan pronto como se detecta la palabra Pokemon, se procesa la lista que se tenía hasta ese momento y luego se vacía otra vez.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu aporte! Me ha servido bastante. 

He añadido un ejemplo del archivo, espero poder procesar los datos correctamente para guardarlos en un diccionario.

Comment: Abusando un poco más de tu tiempo, tengo una duda, he estado haciendo pruebas con base en tu código. ¿Podrías decirme porque si tengo 3 elementos dentro de index_info = [], sólo estoy obteniendo los datos de dos elementos?

Comment: Sí, es porque los elementos de la lista determinan el inicio-fin de cada rodaja. Entonces si tienes por ejemplo la lista `[0, 20, 50]`, las rodajas que obtienes serían la `[0:20]` y la `[20:50]`. El pokemon que comienza en 50 no es incluido porque no hay índice que marque su fin. Podrías usar `[50:]` para obtenerlo. Llevando esto al código de mi respuesta sería hacer un `procesar_pokemon(text[fin:])` una vez salgas del bucle. O también podrías incluir en la lista de índices el que corresponda a la última línea del fichero  +1.

Comment: Una disculpa, te juro que es la última pregunta que te haré... :)
He escrito algo de código para procesar el archivo, ¿podrías echarle un vistazo?
Básicamente he guardado los datos, pero cuando hay un dato nuevo o diferente entonces mi código quiebra. Anexo mi código en el post original.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ya logré resolverlo.

Disculpa las molestías.